# nmap output in CSV format sorted by IP address

Tags: awk, nmap

I have this command which works well to give me a list of IP addresses, MAC addresses, and MAC vendor, sorted by IP address.

```
sudo nmap -sn 192.168.103.0/24 | awk '/Nmap scan report for/{printf $5;}/MAC Address:/{print ","substr($0, index($0,$3)) }' | sort -t . -k 4,4n
```

All I need to do is change my awk print statement so that it puts a comma between the 2nd and 3rd column.  So basically I will end up with 3 columns, column 1 is IP address, column 2 is MAC address, column 3 is MAC vendor name, with all rows sorted by IP address. I got everything I want except the comma between the 2nd and 3rd column.  This will be a CSV file for input into a database.

Comment: If you want to delete your question, delete it, but don't vandalize the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution will be to pipe the result to another awk .

```
nmap -sn 192.168.103.0/24 | \
    awk '/Nmap scan report for/{printf $5;}/MAC Address:/{print ","substr($0, index($0,$3)) }' | \
    awk '{ print $1","$2" "$3" "$4" "$5" "$6 }' | tr -d '()'  | sort -t . -k 4,4n
```

The begin of this command is the same i added only **awk '{ print $1","$2" "$3" "$4" "$5" "$6 }'** to add the second coma

And **tr -d '()'** is here to remove parenthesis arround the Mac Vendor .